# In what way are overstayers issued their entry bans upon departing the UK?

Tags: uk, visa-bans

Title should say it all, really... Are you issued a letter? Stamp in your passport? Told verbally? At what stage in the airport does this happen?

Comment: Can you give answers for the various possible scenarios?

Comment: If you are talking about a voluntary departure, the UK has no exit checks so any action UK immigration wishes to take will trigger on your next attempt at entry and you will get papers detailing the situation then.  If its an enforced departure, you get issued papers well beforehand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the UK has no exit checks, it depends on the circumstances of departure as to when any notice of action against you is given.

If you have come to the attention of the UK immigration authorities while still in the country, you will be issued paperwork at that time.

If you leave voluntarily, you will not be issued further paperwork during your departure (as UK immigration will only be aware of your departure after it occurs as airlines, ferry companies etc update them on passenger details).

If you leave involuntarily (ie you are detained and deported or removed), you will be issued final paperwork at that point.

If you have left voluntarily without coming to the attention of UK immigration while in the country, you may be given notice of subsequent action on your next interaction with the UK immigration system

- if you attempt to enter the UK as a non-visa national, you may get turned away from the border with paperwork detailing any ban
- if you apply for Entry Clearance (a visa) before travelling, the application may be refused with appropriate paperwork detailing why and any subsequent action being taken against you.

If you have any doubt about your eligibility to enter the UK, then the suggestion is always to seek Entry Clearance before you attempt to travel to the UK or Ireland (as Ireland is part of the Common Travel Area, significant amounts of data is shared between these countries).

Comment: *UK immigration will only be aware of your departure after it occurs* Great answer, but I don’t believe this is correct. UK authorities get passenger lists in advance, I believe. Certainly they also receive the final manifest too.

Comment: @MJeffryes that is true, I stretched the definition here because ultimately UKVI don't care to pursue you if you are actually already leaving - they will update their records and get you on the next entry point.  And only the final manifest is the true indication of factual events - a purchased ticket is only evidence of a purchased ticket, not a willing to leave or an actual departure.

Comment: I think it would only be relevant if you were wanted for a crime. Indeed UKVI prefers people remove themselves so they don’t need to go to the trouble, but you’re right that you can’t fool them by buying a ticket and not using it.